# How to upgrade from 3.19.0-23-generic to 3.19.0-25 generic

Tags: upgrade

What is the recommended procedure to upgrade from  3.19.0-23-generic to 3.19.0-25 generic ?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to simply update your system.

The current kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.3 and 15.04 is already 3.19.0-26.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and you will get all routine updates.

Comment: I am suspecting a kernel bug in 3.19.0-25 which is not present in 3.19.0-23. That is why I specifically want to try 3.19.0-25.

Comment: 3.19.0-25 is not good. Lot's of bugs have been fixed in 26.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if there is a way to see the kernel changes between two minor versions (like 3.19.0-25 and 3.19.0-26) ?

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git

Comment: don't you have to run dist-upgrade to update kernels this way?

Comment: @mchid Nothing is removed. It must be just `upgrade`.

Comment: I believe dist-upgrade makes *changes* to the way the system works and will not uninistall or *install* any new packages. Unlike other packages, kernels are available as individual packages instead of newer versions. Having something like linux-generic is supposed to install the newest kernel package available and not the newest version so this is considered installing a new package.

Comment: debian is different

Answer (score 0):

To use the latest available kernel releases for your Ubuntu release, install the package `linux-generic`

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

---

From `apt-cache show linux-generic`

```
Description-en: Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
 This package will always depend on the latest complete generic Linux kernel
 and headers.
```

Comment: Reinstall is not needed, if a version is higher, apt will upgrade this package and pull the latest kernel.